# Publish Wizard - No option to publish to folder

Tags: c#, winforms, publish

I have a Windows desktop application using .NET 4.8.1.  This is an older application I've had to update.  When I last worked on it a few years ago, there was an option to 'Publish to Folder'.

Now however, when the 'Publish Wizard' runs, on the "How will users install the application?" screen, there are only three options:

- From a Web site
- From a UNC path or file share
- From a CD-ROM or DVD-ROM

I just want to deploy to a folder like before!

My application talks to a local SQL installation.  I tried the CD option but I can't work out where the config file is to modify the connection string.  This isn't the solution I want anyway - I just want to be able to deploy to a folder.

As a lesser solution, can I just take what's in the bin/debug folder and use that?